# ipywidgets use container inside Tab

Tags: tabwidget, ipywidgets

Need to set an ipywidget container widget(HBox, VBox, ect.) inside a Tab 
The following is a dummy example of what I trying to do just using a list of Text widgets as a stand in for any other widget

Create a list of what will be in the VBox widget, bind this list of widgets to a VBox, then display that resulting VBox; and this works as expected:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

#just "dummy" widgets for exsample
subwids=[widgets.Text(value='Hello City'), 
 widgets.Text(value='Hello State'), 
 widgets.Text(value='Hello country '), 
 widgets.Text(value='Hello Contant'),
 widgets.Text(value='Hello Continent')
]

#bind the dummy widgets to a VBox
BOX=widgets.VBox(subwids)
#display the VBox
display(BOX)
```

Now I am trying to set the existing VBox in a Tab in the Tab widget, and this is where it won't work and throws an error that can be seen when running the following:

```
tab=widgets.Tab(BOX)
tab.set_title(0, 'GeoLevels')
display(tab)
```

But what I would want it to do is except the VBox in the tab just like I would do in Qt

Answer (score 1):

When I reproduced your example I ran into:

> **TraitError**: The 'children' trait of a Tab instance must be a tuple, but a value of class 'ipywidgets.widgets.widget_box.VBox' was specified.

Following which, I passed it as a tuple:

```
tab=widgets.Tab((BOX,))
tab.set_title(0, 'GeoLevels')
display(tab)
```

Now it displays the tab.